# iconv -l output differs when passed to pipe

Tags: linux, iconv

I've found that `iconv -l` output on Linux differs when I pass it thru a pipe.

```
$ iconv -l
The following list contain all the coded character sets known.  This does
not necessarily mean that all combinations of these names can be used for
the FROM and TO command line parameters.  One coded character set can be
listed with several different names (aliases).

  437, 500, 500V1, 850, 851, 852, 855, 856, 857, 858, 860, 861, 862, 863, 864,
  865, 866, 866NAV, 869, 874, 904, 1026, 1046, 1047, 8859_1, 8859_2, 8859_3,
  8859_4, 8859_5, 8859_6, 8859_7, 8859_8, 8859_9, 10646-1:1993,
...
```

and

```
$ iconv -l | cat
437//
500//
500V1//
...
```

`iconv --version` gives:

```
$ iconv --version
iconv (GNU libc) 2.17
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Ulrich Drepper.
```

Why does this happen? Where is this difference documented? `man iconv` doesn't mention this difference.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical behaviour for many programs. As user "rowboat" mentioned, some programs check if the output will be a terminal or not by using the `isatty` function.

Another example of this behaviour is the `ls` command that will output one line per file in a folder instead of listing it for the terminal:

```
$ ls
a.out   b.out   c.out

$ ls | cat
a.out
b.out
c.out
```

For `ls`, this behaviour is documented in the man page, but for `iconv` it seems not.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I'm trying to understand the "piped" output.  In particular, what is the meaning of "//" at end of each line?

Comment: My guess would be that this is simply a delimiter for aliases, as I have entries like `ISO-10646/UTF-8/`.